# Get value from html select to form action html

Tags: php, html

Hi everyone i'm new here in stackoverflow so.. my first question is:
How i can get the value from HTML `<select></select>` and declare in `<form action="here i want to declare">`

**html**

```
<div class="panel-body">

                <select required>
                 <option value="#">Select Type of File</option>
                 <option value="upload1.php">uno</option>
                 <option value="upload2.php">dos</option>
                 <option value="upload3.php">tres</option>
                </select>

                <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <h4 class="text-center">Cargar Multiple Archivos</h4>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Archivos</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="archivo[]" name="archivo[]" multiple="">
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cargar</button>
                    </div>

                </form>

            </div>
```

I want to get the value upload1.php, or upload2.php or upload3.php depending the option selected on the select HTML and declare in `<form action="HERE"></form>`

The project is cloud to upload files and i want to sort out if is music to a concret folder (upload1.php) if is photos in another folder (upload2.php)

Comment: **Hint:** JavaScript. You need to post what you have tried so far, and, Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: i don't know how i can do it that's why I'm here..

Comment: You need to show some effort before we can help you out, check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Probably you don't need to have multiple upload scripts. Send the type in post instead (`<select name="type"><option value="music">Music</option></select>`).

Comment: David, the multiple uploads are because in upload1.php the directory is /music and in upload2.php directory change to /photos

Comment: people are trying to tell you that you are heading the wrong way. Also that you need more research into Javascript  (at least) before you post here. Welcome to SO, but I have to vote down for now. Keep on improving.

Comment: Hint #2: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp you should be able to understand and use things described on this page at which point the question you asked will have an obvious answer in your head.

Comment: Also, this problem can be solved by means of PHP alone, which tells me you might want to research that too. Either way - start somewhere - you won't be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I would use jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(select).on('change', function() {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $('#form1').prop('action', selected);
    });
});
```

But it is good to give id to select field first.